# MVC4 return value after the initial view receive data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am crating a little application with MVC4, I create the data base and every time a user call
a url in a phone like `myweb.com/xxxuuu`, was able to show the information.

But now I would like to split the info like name and telephone when you click in my info. Another click on Links to show My email and facebooklink.

```
 public ActionResult Entry2(string id)
    {            
        DataSet1.userDataTable table = adapter.GetDatafromuserprofile(id);

        ViewBag.username = table.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();

        ViewData["userid"] = table.Rows[0]["userid"].ToString();

        ViewData["username"] = table.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();

        ViewData["userphone"] = table.Rows[0]["userphone"].ToString();

        ViewData["useremail"] = table.Rows[0]["useremail"].ToString();

        ViewData["userlink1"] = table.Rows[0]["userlink1"].ToString();

        ViewData["userlink2"] = table.Rows[0]["userlink2"].ToString();

        ViewData["usermessage"] = table.Rows[0]["usermessage"].ToString();

        return View();

        //var midata = adapter.obtenervalor(id);
    }
```

This is my router:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Me", action = "Entry2" }
);
```

but I can't find the way to send the id to the controller and get the additional data for the user `xxxuuu`.

I hope this is clear and you can give me a solution.
This is the initial result for my view but when I click on My Links I am returning a null value.

```
ID: xxxuuu
henry@email.com
Henry 
•   Navigation
•   My Info
•   Contact Me
•   My Links
•   My Message
```